# How big is the threshold that is usually used in determining the convergence of loss values in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, convergence

In deep learning, one way to determine whether the training has converged is to observe the movement of the loss values over iterations or epochs. One can choose any $\epsilon$ threshold and any metric. If the value is less than $\epsilon$, then the training has converged.

My question is: how big is the $\epsilon$ value that is usually used? Are there examples of papers that specifically state the threshold?

Answer (score 0):

There is no threshold reference value. Different tasks, losses and datasets lead to radically different loss value ranges and different amounts of noise. This is a somewhat experimentally defined thing.

Also, the training stop criterion is not always based on a threshold. Many times, you just set the training to last for N epochs.